# Domain Object and Controller Class

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, controller

What is the difference between controller class and a domain object? I had a class that contains the fields to describe the entity and some one suggested that is a domain object!
What are those two, if anyone could clearly define both to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Domain object, in this case; is the business logic of the application. It holds data and performs services separate from the view.

The controller class is what is in between the model(domain)-view-controller logic. The view passes information through the controller class to the domain objects. This way your code structure is nice and abstracted out and has good logic!

Comment: you mean domain is like the model? Domain objects are the models, right?